# uwnd variable in netCDF file

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

How do I read a uwnd variable in a netCDF file in python?

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from netCDF4 import Dataset, date2index
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
from IPython.display import Image
from IPython.core.display import HTML 
import netCDF4 as nc
plt.clf()
nc_file = '042711_V.nc'
nc_file2 = '042711_U.nc'
V = Dataset(nc_file, mode='r')
U = Dataset(nc_file2, mode='r')
print U.variables
```

This verifies that uwnd is indeed a variable, but why won't it read?

```
OrderedDict([(u'lat', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 lat(lat)
    units: degrees_north
    actual_range: [ 90. -90.]
    long_name: Latitude
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (73,)
filling off
), (u'lon', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 lon(lon)
    units: degrees_east
    long_name: Longitude
    actual_range: [   0.   357.5]
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (144,)
filling off
), (u'time', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float64 time(time)
    units: hours since 1800-1-1 00:00:0.0
    long_name: Time
    actual_range: [ 71870952.  71870952.]
    delta_t: 0000-01-00 00:00:00
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (1,)
filling off
), (u'uwnd', <type 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
float32 uwnd(time, lat, lon)
    long_name: u wind
    valid_range: [-99999.  99999.]
    actual_range: [ -26.84999084  377.20001221]
    units: m/s
    add_offset: 0.0
    scale_factor: 1.0
    missing_value: -9.96921e+36
    precision: 99
    least_significant_digit: 99
    var_desc: u wind
    dataset: CDC Derived NCEP Reanalysis Products
    level_desc:  500mb Pressure Level
    statistic: Composite
    parent_stat: Other
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (1, 73, 144)
filling off
)])

KeyError: 'uwnd'
```

I'm trying to plot some widnbarbs on the map. i have successfully gotten it to read the time, longitude, and latitude, bu what does the uwnd mean and how do I read it into the numpy format?

Here is the site I found on how to read netCDF files:
http://www.hydro.washington.edu/~jhamman/hydro-logic/blog/2013/10/12/plot-netcdf-data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*edit* After [discussing](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96789/discussion-between-bart-and-brian-b) it in more detail, it turns out that `uwnd` was called `vwnd` in the other (`042711_U.nc`) file, resulting in the `KeyError`

---

Do you get the `KeyError` (or the entire output that you show) from the last print statement in your code? Normally something like this should read `uwnd` into a 3D Numpy array:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
U = Dataset('042711_U.nc', 'r')
uwnd = U.variables["uwnd"][:,:,:]
```

For example, with a slightly different meteorological dataset:

```
import netCDF4 as nc4
nc = nc4.Dataset('drycblles.default.0000000.nc')
u = nc.variables["u"][:,:]
print(type(u), u.shape)
```

> `<class 'numpy.ndarray'> (8, 32)`

Comment: I tried adjusting it to what you have and I still get a key error for "uwnd" not being found. I agree the format matches, but I still get the error.

Comment: Just to be sure, could you post the output of `ncdump -h 042711_U.nc` somewhere?

Comment: I'm working in IPython Notebook, so I get:

  File "<ipython-input-101-3b65ee6dc97d>", line 1
    ncdump -h 042711_U.nc
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant to run the `ncdump` utility from the command line, outside of Python. But I'm still a bit puzzled; is the entire output that you are showing (incl. `KeyError: 'uwnd'`) from the `print U.variables` statement?

Comment: To clarify, the output from U.variables is separate from the KeyError.

Comment: In that case, could you post the actual line of code that causes the error?

Comment: ---> 23 uwnd = V.variables["uwnd"][:,:,:]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96789/discussion-between-bart-and-brian-b).